# Parallel Aggregration of a collection using PPL or TBB

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, aggregation, ppl, parallel.for

I've decided to write an algorithm to utilize parallel aggregation. Here is the single threaded code that I want to transform.

```
vector<vector<double>> sum;

for (const auto* fold : _obj.GetFolds())
     sum.push_back(move(vector<double>(fold->GetSize())));

for (int index : sequence)
{
     vector<vector<double>> values = Calculate(vec1[index], vec2[index]);

     for (int i = 0; i < sum.size(); i++)
     {
          for (int j = 0; j < sum[i].size(); j++)
               sum[i][j] += values[i][j];
     }
}
```

I looked at the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg663540.aspx which covers parallel_for with combinable, and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470426.aspx#map_reduce_example showing parallel_transform with parallel_reduce, but they are simple examples with only a counter.

```
vector<int> sequence = ...

  combinable<int> count([]() { return 0; });     

  parallel_for_each(sequence.cbegin(), sequence.cend(), 
    [&count](int i)
    {
        count.local() += IsPrime(i) ? 1 : 0;
    });
  return count.combine(plus<int>());
```

I'm having a difficult time finding examples where I would aggregate with a parallel loop the `vector<vector<double>> sum` as outlined above.

Also, I'm looking for advice on whether to use parallel_for and combinable or parallel_transform with parallel_reduce? The first link above states:

> The parallel_reduce function is usually the recommended approach
>   whenever you need to apply the Parallel Aggregation pattern within
>   applications that use PPL. Its declarative nature makes it less prone
>   to error than other approaches, and its performance on multicore
>   computers is competitive with them. Implementing parallel aggregation
>   with parallel_reduce doesn't require adding locks in your code.
>   Instead, all the synchronization occurs internally. Of course, if
>   parallel_reduce doesn't meet your needs or if you prefer a less
>   declarative style of coding, you can also use the combinable class
>   with parallel_for or parallel_for_each to implement the parallel
>   aggregation.
>
> You should be aware that parallel_for and parallel_for_each add
>   overhead due to their support of features such as cancellation and
>   dynamic range stealing. Also, a call to the combinable::local() method
>   inside of a parallel loop adds the cost of a hash table lookup to each
>   iteration of the loop. In general, use parallel aggregation to
>   increase performance when iterations perform complex computations.

Thanks.